# Create an UiAutomation with C

Tags: c, winapi, ui-automation

I have the following code in C to create the UiAutomation object:

```
#include "UiAutomationclient.h"

IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
      
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CUIAutomation;
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IUIAutomation;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
'function': cannot convert from 'const CLSID' to 'const IID *const '
'function': cannot convert from 'const IID' to 'const IID *const '
```

I do not know what I am doing incorrectly. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code compiles in C++, but in C the function expects *pointers* instead of references.

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IUIAutomation, (void**)&pAutomation);
```

This is because `CoCreateInstance` is [declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) as:

```
HRESULT CoCreateInstance(
  REFCLSID  rclsid,
  LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter,
  DWORD     dwClsContext,
  REFIID    riid,
  LPVOID    *ppv
);
```

But `REFCLSID` and `REFIID` are [conditionally](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/shared/guiddef.h#L125) `#define`'d depending on the target language:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFIID const IID &
#else
#define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFCLSID const IID &
#else
#define REFCLSID const IID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive explanation. Tks for your time.